# Meaning of the Lord God

Tags: meaning

I was doing an exercise in grammar where I had to fill in the correct form of the verb **hide** in a sentence

> Adam and his wife __________ themselves from the presence of **the Lord God**.

Correct form would be hid but I don't understand the meaning of **the Lord God** used in this sentence

Actually what I don't understand is why are **the Lord** and **God** used together when they refer to the same person

Help me understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a specific phrase that appears in the bible and in texts inspired by the bible.

In the Hebrew Bible there is the name of god "YHWH" and the word "elohim" (meaning god or gods) The name of god is so holy that it is common for YHWH to be replaced in speech with "Adonai" or "Lord". In much of the bible god is referred to as "YHWH Elohim". Translators of the Bible have translated "YHWH Elohim" as "Lord God".